# Usando .replace, duda con el for e if

Tags: python

Estaba haciendo un ejercicio de Python que me pide que reemplaze las vocales de una string introducida por el usuario por su número de aparición, ejemplo: Input: Mañana Output: M1ñ2n3.

```
frase_del_usuario = input("Dime una frase: ")
vocales = ["A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u"]

numero_aparicion = 1

for letra in frase_del_usuario:
    if letra in vocales:
        frase_del_usuario = frase_del_usuario.replace(letra, str(numero_aparicion))
        numero_aparicion += 1

print(frase_del_usuario)
```

El Output que me da el código es: M1ñ1n1, en ves de: M1ñ2ñ3.

Agradezco la ayuda!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El problema principal es que:

```
frase_del_usuario.replace(letra, str(numero_aparicion))
```

reemplaza todas las `a` de `mañana`, la primer vuelta con el `1` y luego, los siguientes `replace` se invalidan por que la frase ya es `M1ñ1n1`. Lo más simple que puedes intentar es decirle a [`replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) que solo modifique una ocurrencia:

```
frase_del_usuario = frase_del_usuario.replace(letra, str(numero_aparicion), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta en el uso de *replace*. Este acción te remplaza todas las vocales de iguales en la frase de una sola vez.
Te recomiendo tambien que no modifiques un objeto sobre el cual estas iterando (frase_del_usuario).

```
frase_del_usuario = input("Dime una frase: ")
vocales = ["A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u"]

frase_del_usuario_copia= ""
numero_aparicion = 1

for letra in frase_del_usuario:

    if letra in vocales:
        frase_del_usuario_copia = frase_del_usuario_copia + str(numero_aparicion)
        numero_aparicion += 1
    else:
        frase_del_usuario_copia = frase_del_usuario_copia + letra

print(frase_del_usuario_copia)
```

Answer (score 0):

En el ejercicio, se tendría que reemplazar las vocales de una en una

Ej: frase_del_usuario = Mañana

1er reemplazo seria M1ñana

2do reemplazo seria M1ñ2na

3er reemplazo seria M1ñ2n3

por eso en el .replace("texto", "nuevo_texto", cantidad_a_reemplazar)

Espero te sea de ayuda.

```
frase_del_usuario = raw_input("Dime una frase: ")
vocales = ["A", "a", "E", "e", "I", "i", "O", "o", "U", "u"]

numero_aparicion = 1

for letra in frase_del_usuario:
    if letra in vocales:
        frase_del_usuario = frase_del_usuario.replace(letra, str(numero_aparicion), 1)
        numero_aparicion += 1

print(frase_del_usuario)
```

Comment: Agrega una explicación de la respuesta que no es bien vista una respuesta como solo código.